# I'm not sure how to solve this error

Tags: c++, compiler-errors

I am not experienced in c++ - I started today and I don't understand why I get a compile error. The info is below the code.

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    using namespace std;
    cout << "Would you like to use this program?";
    string yn;
    cin >> yn;
    if (yn == "y")
{
    cout << "Continuing...";
}
else {
    cout << "Exiting...";
}
return 0;
}
```

The section "cin >> yn;" is what is apparently causing a compile error and the ">>" are underlined in red, does anyone know what I have done wrong? Also I am using Microsoft Visual Studio 2013 if that might have anything to do with it.

Comment: And what is the error you receive? Don't make us guess. (I can't reproduce the problem; it compiles fine over here on g++.)

Comment: Did you include string? #include <string>

Comment: @ComradeBearabyte Wouldn't that cause an error on the line `string yn;` instead?

Comment: @cdhowie it is probably forward declared in iostream

Comment: @ComradeBearabyte You'd still get an error on `string yn;` then, because you can't declare a variable of an incomplete type.

Comment: @cdhowie haha I don't know then mate, just trying to help

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to include header `<string>`

```
#include <string>
```

It is this header where `operator <<` and `operator >>` are declared for class `std::string` (`std::basic_string`)

Comment: Thank you I only just started c++ yesterday :)

Comment: @Tom Strong Good luck!:)